# Error LSTM sentiment analysis using Tensorflow - ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, tensorflow, sentiment-analysis, lstm

I am learning LSTM model for sentiment analysis.

Below is the code that generates the feature sets from 5000 positive and negative sentences:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import numpy as np
import random
from collections import Counter
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
hm_lines = 100000

def create_lexicon(pos, neg):
    lexicon = []
    with open(pos, 'r') as f:
        contents = f.readlines()    
        for l in contents[:len(contents)]:
            l= l.decode('utf-8')
            all_words = word_tokenize(l)
            lexicon += list(all_words)
    f.close()

    with open(neg, 'r') as f:
        contents = f.readlines()        
        for l in contents[:len(contents)]:
            l= l.decode('utf-8')
            all_words = word_tokenize(l)
            lexicon += list(all_words)
    f.close()

    lexicon = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(i) for i in lexicon]
    w_counts = Counter(lexicon)
    l2 = []
    for w in w_counts:
        if 1000 > w_counts[w] > 50:
            l2.append(w)
    print("Lexicon length create_lexicon: ",len(lexicon))
    return l2

def sample_handling(sample, lexicon, classification):
    featureset = []
    print("Lexicon length Sample handling: ",len(lexicon))
    with open(sample, 'r') as f:
        contents = f.readlines()
        for l in contents[:len(contents)]:
            l= l.decode('utf-8')
            current_words = word_tokenize(l.lower())
            current_words= [lemmatizer.lemmatize(i) for i in current_words]
            features = np.zeros(len(lexicon))
            for word in current_words:
                if word.lower() in lexicon:
                    index_value = lexicon.index(word.lower())
                    features[index_value] +=1

            features = list(features)
            featureset.append([features, classification])
    f.close()
    print("Feature SET------")
    print(len(featureset))
    return featureset

def create_feature_sets_and_labels(pos, neg, test_size = 0.1):
    global m_lexicon
    m_lexicon = create_lexicon(pos, neg)
    features = []
    features += sample_handling(pos, m_lexicon, [1,0])
    features += sample_handling(neg, m_lexicon, [0,1])
    random.shuffle(features)
    features = np.array(features)
    testing_size = int(test_size * len(features))

    train_x = list(features[:,0][:-testing_size])
    train_y = list(features[:,1][:-testing_size])
    test_x = list(features[:,0][-testing_size:])
    test_y = list(features[:,1][-testing_size:])

    return train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y

def get_lexicon():
    global m_lexicon
    return m_lexicon
```

Below is the code for LSTM:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn
from create_sentiment_featuresets import create_feature_sets_and_labels
from create_sentiment_featuresets import get_lexicon

import numpy as np

# extras for testing
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize 
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
#- end extras

train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y = create_feature_sets_and_labels('pos.txt', 'neg.txt')

print(len(train_x))
print(len(train_x[0]))
input_vec_size= len(train_x[0])  # = lstm size
hm_epochs = 3
n_classes = 2
batch_size = 100
rnn_size = 128      # hidden layers

x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, input_vec_size, n_classes])
y = tf.placeholder('float')

def recurrent_neural_network(x):
    layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([rnn_size, n_classes])), 'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}

    x = tf.transpose(x, [1,0,2])
    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, input_vec_size])
    x = tf.split(x, 2, 0)

    lstm_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size, state_is_tuple=True)
    outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype= tf.float32)
    output = tf.matmul(outputs[-1], layer['weights']) + layer['biases']
    return output


def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = recurrent_neural_network(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits= prediction, labels= y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate= 0.001).minimize(cost)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            i = 0
            while i < len(train_x):
                start = i
                end = i+ batch_size
                batch_x = train_x[start: end]
                batch_y = train_y[start: end]

                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict= {x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
                epoch_loss += c
                i+= batch_size
            print('Epoch', epoch+ 1, 'completed out of ', hm_epochs, 'loss:', epoch_loss)

        correct= tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))

        print('Accuracy:', accuracy.eval({x:test_x, y:test_y}))

        # prediction for single --------------
        m_lexicon= get_lexicon()
        print('Lexicon length: ',len(m_lexicon))

        input_data= "David likes to go out with Kary"

        current_words= word_tokenize(input_data.lower())
        current_words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(i) for i in current_words]
        features = np.zeros(len(m_lexicon))

        for word in current_words:
            if word.lower() in m_lexicon:
                index_value = m_lexicon.index(word.lower())
                features[index_value] +=1

        features = np.array(list(features)).reshape(1,-1)       # if reshape is remove, add x:[features]
        print('features length: ',len(features))
        result = sess.run(tf.argmax(prediction.eval(feed_dict={x:features}), 1))
        print('RESULT: ', result)
        print(prediction.eval(feed_dict={x:features}))
        if result[0] == 0:
            print('Positive: ', input_data)
        elif result[0] == 1:
            print('Negative: ', input_data)

train_neural_network(x)
```

The above code is giving the following error:

```
2017-06-07 16:36:52.775649: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-06-07 16:36:52.775682: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-06-07 16:36:52.775702: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-06-07 16:36:52.775714: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-06-07 16:36:52.775724: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-06-07 16:36:53.094522: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:901] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2017-06-07 16:36:53.094925: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:887] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce 930MX
major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.0195
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 1.96GiB
Free memory: 1.76GiB
2017-06-07 16:36:53.094958: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:908] DMA: 0 
2017-06-07 16:36:53.094966: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 0:   Y 
2017-06-07 16:36:53.094975: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:977] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0,         name: GeForce 930MX, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sentiment_demo_lstm2.py", line 119, in <module>
    train_neural_network(x)
  File "sentiment_demo_lstm2.py", line 79, in train_neural_network
    _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict= {x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
  File "/home/lsmpc/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 778, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/lsmpc/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 961, in _run
    % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (100, 423) for Tensor u'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 423, 2)'
```

Please help.

Also I am having difficulty understanding this part:

```
x = tf.transpose(x, [1,0,2])
x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, input_vec_size])
x = tf.split(x, 2, 0)
```

**Output of**

```
print(train_x[0])
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

print(train_y[0])
[0, 1]
```

len(train_x)= 9596, len(train_x[0]) = 423

Thanks.

Comment: What is the shape of `train_x`? It looks like `x` expects a tensor of shape (None, 423, 2) but receives on of shape (100, 423).

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more how your data looks like, what you want to predict and how you want to do that with an RNN?

Comment: @sietschie len(train_x)= 9596, len(train_x[0]) = 423

Comment: I see that you are trying to modify some MNIST example. The mnist data is shaped `(numSamples, 28, 28)`. You should reshape your data to be `(numSamples,423,1)`, set `chunk_size` to 1 and `n_chunks` to 423. Then I would expect it to work with the original code. I think with your modifications here you mixed up some things. For example the `reshape` and `split` part seems wrong now.

Comment: @sietschie Please have a look at this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/44386348/8070652